# script (called from script tag) is not available while doing jest testing

Tags: javascript, dom, jestjs

script  tag is not available while doing jest testing

public/index.html content

```
script src="config.js" //script tag
```

---

public/config.js content

```
window.appConfig = {
    oboServicePath: 'some path'
}
```

---

axios.ts

```
const axiosOBOInstance = axios.create({
    // @ts-ignore
    adapter: cacheAdapterEnhancer(axios.defaults.adapter, {
    defaultCache,
}),
baseURL: appConfig.getRequired('oboServicePath'),
```

Error at

> appConfig.getRequired as window.appConfig is undefined

appConfig should be available @window scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jest` just runs the code in the unit tests and doesn't know about the script tags in `index.html`.

`appConfig` will need to be added to `window` as part of the setup for the unit tests.

It looks like `public/config.js` contains setup code that should run before every test.

If you are using `Jest` by itself you can tell `Jest` to run `public/config.js` before every test using [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) or [setupTestFrameworkScriptFile](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string).

If you are using [`create-react-app`](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/) then create `src/setupTests.js` if it doesn't already exist (`src/setupTests.ts` if you are using TypeScript) and add your setup code.  That file ["will be automatically executed before running your tests"](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#initializing-test-environment).

Comment: Getting error - react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom --coverage "AppHeaderView.test.tsx"

Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these Jest options:

  • collectCoverageFrom
  • coverageReporters
  • coverageThreshold
  • snapshotSerializers
  • moduleNameMapper.

These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:

  • setupFiles

If you wish to override other Jest options, you need to eject from the default setup. I do not want to eject the project... so do we have any other options.

Comment: @sunilsharma I added details about adding setup code to an app bootstrapped with `create-react-app`

Comment: this does not solve the problem though, which is that code in script tags is not called, right?